# Fetching External API data with React: this.state is empty

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying without luck to resolve an issue with fetching data from an API. I'm thinking that it could be because of the JSON structure that is preventing setState from being successfully done.

the console log shows an empty array returned.

**myresults.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/data/races/all';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data[0]}));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.results);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.results}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**JSON of localhost:8080/data/races/all:**

```
[
  {
    "url": "www",
    "year": 2018,
    "Name": "Rabbit",
    "Id": 1
  },
  {
    "url": "www",
    "year": 2018,
    "Name": "Cat",
    "Id": 2
  },
  {
    "url": "www",
    "year": 2018,
    "Name": "Dog",
    "Id": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: The array will be empty until the request is completed. [Are you sure it should be `data[0]` and not just `data` in your `setState`](https://codesandbox.io/s/3144rw0n95)?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that data back from your `fetch` call? You might want to try doing `fetch(URL).then(console.log)` to make sure you get the data.

Comment: please try this :  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  } and tell us what shows the console.

Comment: @Ivo (EDIT: Sorry, i'm getting a "Objects are not valid as a React child" error. The next step is for me to render elements from am array). Thanks!

Comment: Map your data to React elements then in `render`. E.g. `{this.state.results.map(item => <span>{item.Name}</span>)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the comments set your state with all the returned data, not set just one item. After getting your data, you need to map through it to render your DOM. Do not use the whole data like `this.state.results`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/data/races/all';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
  }

  render() {
        return (
      <div>{
        this.state.results.map( result => (
          <ul>
            <li>{result.url}</li>
            <li>{result.year}</li>
            <li>{result.Name}</li>
            <li>{result.Id}</li>
          </ul>
        ) )
      }
      </div> );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is an example mimicking your situation:

```js
const data = [
  {
    url: "www",
    year: 2018,
    Name: "Rabbit",
    Id: 1,
  },
  {
    url: "www",
    year: 2018,
    Name: "Cat",
    Id: 2,
  },
  {
    url: "www",
    year: 2018,
    Name: "Dog",
    Id: 3,
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    results: [],
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData().then( results => this.setState( {
      results,
    } ) );
  }

  getData() {
    return new Promise( resolve => resolve( data ) );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{
        this.state.results.map( result => (
          <ul>
            <li>{result.url}</li>
            <li>{result.year}</li>
            <li>{result.Name}</li>
            <li>{result.Id}</li>
          </ul>
        ) )
      }
      </div> );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```